# React router not matching any route, always goes to 404 route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

React router can't match any route and always shows last (`NotFound`) component. Everything works fine if I use `BrowserRouter` from `'react-router-dom'` instead of `Router`. But I have to use `Router` because I have to use custom history (for which I am using `history` library). Heres my code.

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import ExpenseDashboardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashboardPage';
import AddExpensePage from '../components/AddExpensePage';
import EditExpensePage from '../components/EditExpensePage';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';

export let history = createBrowserHistory();

function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
          <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
          <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem, works fine on my end.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to /dashboard or /create or other routes?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's a good idea to create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce the problem here's a working sandbox, tell me if I'm missing something https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mendeleev-xegqj?file=/src/App.js:0-1014.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `react-router-dom` version 5.x is not compatible with `history` version 5.0.0. I switched to `history` version 4.x and now its working as expected.

Comment: I tested `react-router-dom` version `5.2.0` and `history` version `5.0.0` and that works on my end.

Comment: First. thanks for putting the effort to create the sandbox. After reading this comment, I went back and uninstalled version 4.x of history and installed the most recent version (5.0.0) and the app broke with the same problem as mentioned in this question.

Comment: I edited the sandbox you created to reproduce the issue. I think I have reproduced the issue now. See here https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-leftpad-s6v15?file=/src/index.js
On `index.js` I am checking if user is logged in with `user = true` (meaning logged in) or not and then routing the user. If user is not logged in I route them to `LoginPage` component. If you make `user = false`, then routes stop working and you always land on `NotFound` component, instead of `LoginPage` component. This only happens when I use version `5.0.0` of `history`. Sorry, I shld have included it in main question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't fit the question but in my case, i included a different component in Switch component. Switch component should only have Route components in them.